# How to ordering MVC Bundles in async load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I've designed a website by `MVC 4`. Now, I had a problem with the timing of resource loading and execution of scripts. Because, The libraries that have higher priority (such as `jQuery`) and should be run at the first, but loaded later of others, and scripts are dependent on them loaded and run earlier are causing to errors!

My bundles of scripts is:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                           "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                           "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/jquery.knob.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/toastr.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                           "~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/smoothscrool.js", 
                           "~/Scripts/scrollReveal.js",
                           "~/Scripts/easing.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/site.js"));


bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/contact").Include(
            "~/Scripts/contact.js"));
```

This is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" async></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")

    <div id="page-content">        
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, at the beginning of body, the scripts to be loaded **async**:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" async></script>", "~/bundles/scripts")
```

And this is my Contact View razor codes:

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/contact")
}

<div>
   Contact Contents
</div>
```

Now, although section script is loaded in the end of the body. But due to the asynchronous loading of resources, dependent script loaded earlier (Because it is more compact than the layout scripts) and caused to error!

How to force dependent scripts to run after running all layout asynchronous scripts !?

Comment: Sounds like you want the thing to just spit out one tag/file with everything ordered correctly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts.renderformat(v=vs.110).aspx *RenderFormat generates script tags for the supplied paths using the specified format string. It generates multiple script tags for each item in the bundle when EnableOptimizations is set to false. When optimizations are enabled, it generates a single script tag to a version-stamped URL which represents the entire bundle.* You'd need one bundle per view with scripts, though.

Comment: @ta.speot.is EnableOptimizations is true. My contact.js script just used in Contact view, So, is this right to add it in layout bundle, then this script loaded in all pages!

Comment: *You'd need one bundle per view*

Comment: @ta.speot.is thank you for guids.

Comment: The answer below seems to be a good solution. Personally, I haven't found async to be very useful. Just put the script tag at the end of the <body> to get a similar end result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the layout view you should add a dynamic bundle for add resources to every view when that view called from layout.
in the other words, you can generate script bundle and styles bundle within one file to every view by define any view resources in the dynamic bundle class.

For Example :

class BundleConfig in this path `App_Start\BundleConfig`:

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            var styles = new string[]
            {
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-select.min.css",
                "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                "~/Content/toastr.min.css",
                "~/Content/front.css",
                "~/Content/style.css"
            };

            var zocial = new string[] { "~/Content/zocial.css" };

            var gridmvc = new string[]
            {
                "~/Content/Gridmvc.css",
                "~/Content/gridmvc.datepicker.min.css"
            };

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/stylesheets").Include(styles));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/stylesheets-zocial").Include(styles.Concat(zocial).ToArray()));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/stylesheets-gridmvc").Include(styles.Concat(gridmvc).ToArray()));


        }
}


public static class BundleExtensions
{
        public static string GetViewBundleName(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, BundleType bundleType)
        {
            var controller = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            var action = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

                    switch (controller.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "home":
                            {
                                switch (action.ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "index": return "~/Content/stylesheets-homepage";
                                    default:
                                        return "~/Content/stylesheets";
                                }
                            }
                        case "sitemaps":
                            return "~/Content/stylesheets-zocial";

                        case "blogs":
                            return "~/Content/stylesheets-gridmvc";

                        case "account":
                            return "~/Content/stylesheets-jqueryval";


                        default:
                            return "~/Content/stylesheets";
                    }
        }
}
```

At last, in the layout, must be add scripts this model for async:

```
Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" async></script>", Html.GetViewBundleName(BundleType.Scripts)))
```

Comment: Sure This is a nice answer especially the GetViewBundleName() extension. but when you use Scripts.RenderFormat() Asp.Net will convert boundles to single links. so you will have multiple non-compressed files to call, and that is not what bundles means in Asp.Net.